How to create a dynamic plot in python jupyter notebook using a for loop?
I am following this lesson on solving the heat equation in python. The lesson states that after solving the heat equation, we can visualize the solution by simply calling pyplot.plot() inside the loop for an animated plot, where the code below will dynamically plot the temperature at every point at every time, resulting in an animated plot (an example of the animated plot is provided in the lesson post).
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

length = 2
k = .466
temp_left = 200
temp_right = 200

total_time = 4

dx = .1
x_vec = numpy.linspace(0, length, int(length/dx))

dt = .0001
t_vec = numpy.linspace(0, total_time, int(total_time/dt))

u = numpy.zeros([len(t_vec), len(x_vec)])

u[:, 0] = temp_left
u[:, -1] = temp_right

for t in range(1, len(t_vec)-1):
    for x in range(1, len(x_vec)-1):
        u[t+1, x] = k * (dt / dx**2) * (u[t, x+1] - 2*u[t, x] +
                                        u[t, x-1]) + u[t, x]

    pyplot.plot(x_vec, u[t], 'black')
    pyplot.pause(.001)
    pyplot.cla()


pyplot.plot(x_vec, u[0])
pyplot.ylabel("Temperature (C˚)")
pyplot.xlabel("Distance Along Rod (m)")
pyplot.show()

I am just learning to code, and this is all new to me. I am working in a jupyter notebook version 7.1.2. I placed the code into the jupyter notebook cell, ran the cell, and was expecting a single dynamic plot. Instead, what I got was many static plots.
I've looked at the examples found here to see if I can modify the code to work for my application. In trying every example I would get a blank figure, like so:


"I am just learning to code, and this is all new to me."  First, the topic your title covers is already well covered here and should normally not be a new post. Please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the parts about doing research and writing a good specific title. Your title is too broad to say it isn't covered. More specific, and I'd have a harder time saying that. I think the reason I have to qualify with that normally there in my first sentence will be clearer if I give you a better sense of the contributing factors in ...

 play. First, making animated plots is one of the difficult things to get working in Jupyter these days. So that you got as far as you did is to be commended. But why is it that getting an animated plot working in Jupyter right now can be a challenge given there should already be lots of examples? And why did looking around not really help? You probably had a hard time finding the answer to your problem in part because of using old resources and applying them to different and current tech. Case in point you take a lesson written in 2022 for using Python and use the current ...

Jupyter Notebook 7+ to do an animated plot.  No where in that 2022 article does it seem to mention Jupyter? Jupyter does have features making using a Python kernel in it different than using Python directly. So doubling down on the ill-advised approach of using old writing as a source is that you then look for help in even earlier post from 2021 - here. One of the things about open source development is that it can radically shift sometimes, and so you need to pay attention to versions. To your credit you do make clear ...

in your post that you are using Jupyter Notebook 7+. But of course you didn't know that Jupyter Notebook 7+ that just came out last year is radically different than Juyter Notebook versions prior? See the bottom of my answer here for resources that will give you a better sense of how different things have become in the Jupyter ecosystem because Jupyter Notebook 7+ is based on JupyterLab components, unlike all previous versions of the document-centric Jupyter Notebook interface. Another issue not helping you sort all this out...

on your own is that the current ipympl documentation simply says it helps with interactive use of matplotlib in Jupyter and doesn't include an animated plot example among the examples at this time. So hopefully that greater context gives you a better sense of some of the factors in play here and why on one hand I want to say this is covered elsewhere well, because it is. But at the same time I cannot really say that because it is not clearly covered very well given the shift in the tech since 2023. There's too much outdated information making it hard to find the current...

syntax & approaches that work. FWIW, I have a resource for animated plots here, that includeds examples with for loops that you may find helpful teasing out more options to how you could address your particular animation and have it work in different flavors/version of Jupyter. Click the appropriate 'launch binder' badges to get an active session to work through the examples.

@Wayne (+1), thank you for the informative and comprehensive comments. These will help me in my coding journey. Cheers!

Below is a working example of your code. I based it off of a very similar question here. Specifically see BlackHC's answer since I could not get the other answers to work. You will also need to have ipympl installed. %matplotlib widget (magic command) only needs to be run once per notebook. The magic command sets the plotting backend. It takes a very long time to run with the current number of iterations and sleep time.
Edit: Per the suggestion in the comment. This will work in JupyterLab and JupyterNotebook 6+ (6 was released in 2020 and BlackHC's answer here was posted in 2020). You can %matplotlib widget or %matplotlib ipympl per the ipyml website
# install ipympl first
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
import time


length = 2
k = 0.466
temp_left = 200
temp_right = 200

total_time = 4

dx = 0.1
dt = 0.0001
x_vec = np.linspace(0, length, int(length / dx))

t_vec = np.linspace(0, total_time, int(total_time / dt))

u = np.zeros([len(t_vec), len(x_vec)])

u[:, 0] = temp_left
u[:, -1] = temp_right


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
hdisplay = display.display("", display_id=True)

ax.set_xlabel("Temperature (C˚)")
ax.set_ylabel("Distance Along Rod (m)")
for t in range(1, len(t_vec) - 1):
    for x in range(1, len(x_vec) - 1):
        u[t + 1, x] = (
            k * (dt / dx**2) * (u[t, x + 1] - 2 * u[t, x] + u[t, x - 1]) + u[t, x]
        )
    plt.cla()
    ax.plot(x_vec, u[t], "black")
    hdisplay.update(fig)
    time.sleep(0.00001)

plt.close(fig)


The magic %matplotlib statement would be more explicit as %matplotlib ipympl as it is covered in the documentation. The %matplotlib widget works for legacy reasons. %matplotlib ipympl is clearer as that is the package that needs installing.

Plus, I'd point out that the original question that you reference was posted in 2017. The situation in the Jupyter ecosystem is very different now and is large part of the confusion that is in the comments to the top answer there. Your answer would help over that one by making clear is for current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+.
